# android translate animation absolute - from right to left and left to right

Tags: android, android-animation

I have this 2 text views.

http://cl.ly/image/2S0o2O1x470r

signup and login.
behind them there's a View with grey background.
I want to run an animation that when you press that buttons the grey view 
moves to the button along with the view pager content.

when I do an xml translate like that :

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fromXDelta="0%"
android:toXDelta="100%" >
</translate>
```

the animation is going right but when it finishes it comes back to place.

how do I keep it in place?

never did absolute animations before and couldn't find anything useful 
about that issue.

ty

Comment: add `android:fillAfter="true"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it, and i'll post my solution in case anyone else get this problem.

I did it in code and not xml, code:

```
private void rightAnimation() {

    //measures the layout width so the button knows how much to move.
    int xOffset = signUpLoginLayout.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    //the animation - xOffset / 2 is how much I want to move right on the Xline.
    TranslateAnimation moveAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, xOffset, 0, 0);
    moveAnim.setDuration(500);
    moveAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    leftSignUpAnimation.startAnimation(moveAnim);

    moveAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            //that's to move the viewpager to the desired location.
            pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

did the same method to move left just switched the animation 
from (0, xOffset, 0, 0) to (xOffset, 0, 0, 0)

hope this helps someone.

good luck :)